# Regex Replace only working on Last Match

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace the src of a number of image html elements in plain text (before they are rendered in the browser).

Here's what I have so far

```js
var base = './images';
        
var sample = '<p><img src="1.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="2.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="3.png" alt="image-1"></p>';
        
sample = sample.replace(/(<img.+src=")(?!http:\/\/)(.*?)"/g, '$1' + base + '/$2"');
        
$('pre').text(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

However it only replaces the src of the last image element.  What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you are missing the fact that using regex for this is an XY problem. Use the DOM. You don't need to append the elements; create them from the string, and access their `src` property.

Comment: FYI elclanrs doing this in the browser isn't an option unfortunately, as I mentioned I have to do this before it hits the browser (node.js)

Comment: Check out [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio), it'll probably save you time, and bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The greedy match in `<img.+src` is catching everything between the first `img` and the last `src`; your `$1` is therefore

```
<img src="1.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="2.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="
```

Change to a non-greedy match:

```
sample = sample.replace(/(<img.+?src=")(?!http:\/\/)(.*?)"/g, '$1' + base + '/$2"');
```

```js
var base = './images';
        
var sample = '<p><img src="1.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="2.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="3.png" alt="image-1"></p>';
        
sample = sample.replace(/(<img.+?src=")(?!http:\/\/)(.*?)"/g, '$1' + base + '/$2"');
        
$('pre').text(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: that worked like a charm .. guess I need to watch those greedy ones!

Answer (score 1):

As @elclanrs metions in a comment, it seems like you are using the wrong approach here. Changing it trough the DOM via jQuery or the like seems a more appropriate method.

That being said, if, for some reason, this is the opportune way to solve it (I do not know all the variables), you should solve it by making the RegEx more explicit. [Greedy matching generally performs the best](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/greedy-lazy-performance), and having to use lazy evaluation (non-greedy) is generally a sign that either your RegEx is not specific enough, or that you are using RegEx to solve something that should not be solved with RegEx. This should do the trick somewhat:

```js
var base = './images';
        
var sample = '<p><img src="1.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img src="2.png" alt="image-1"></p><p><img alt="image-1" src="3.png"></p>';
        
sample = sample.replace(/(<img[^>]+src=")(?!http:\/\/)([^"]+)"/g, '$1' + base + '/$2"');
        
$('pre').text(sample);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

*Not exactly sure I'm doing the code tags correct though. Still learning to use those.*